# Does not delete the record

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I'm currently working on live search which is works great, when person see the result from live search there is three links of "edit, delete and view"

When I tried to delete one of product information from database by click the delete link, but the problem is that it does not do anything not even errors showing at all...

I'm showing there is no product_id number at the end of url address see the full url ...

```
http://localhost/shopone/admin/live/search-save.php?deleteid=
```

what did I miss in the code?

This section is for getting result from search text field.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['kw']) && $_POST['kw'] != '')
{
  $kws = $_POST['kw'];
  $kws = mysql_real_escape_string($kws); 
  $query = "select * from product where product_name like '%".$kws."%' limit 10" ;
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
  $i = 0;
  if($count > 0)
  {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $product_id = $row["product_id"];

    //Contanter     
    echo "  <div class='container'>";

    //First columns Product Images
    echo "<div class='sidebar1'>";
    echo "<div>";?><a href='$row[$product_name]'><img src="<?php echo $row["screenshot"];?>" width="100" height="100" /></a> 
    <?php echo "</div>" ; 
    echo "</div>";

    //Second columns Product Name
    echo "<div class='content'>";
    echo $row['product_name'];"</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    //3rd columns Product Category
    echo "<div class='sidebar2'>";
    echo $row['product_category'];
    echo "</div>";

    //Fourth columns Product Retail Price
    echo "<div class='sidebar3'>";
    echo $row['product_retail_price'];
    echo "</div>";

    //Fifth columns Product Price
    echo "<div class='sidebar4'>";
    echo $row['product_price'];
    echo "</div>";
    //Sixth columns Product Price
    echo "<div class='sidebar4'>";
    echo "<a href='../data/edit_product.php?pid=' . $product_id . ''>Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href='search-save.php?deleteid=' . $product_id . ''>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href='../data/edit-view.php?pid=' . $product_id . ''>View</a>";

    echo "</div>";

    //End of Container
    echo "</div>";

      $i++;
      if($i == 5) break;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    if($count > 5)
    {
      echo "<div id='view_more'><a href='#'>View more results</a></div>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<div id='no_result'>No result found !</div>";
  }
}
?>
```

and this section is for delete when press delete ....

```
<?php
  //Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
  if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
     echo 'Do you really want to delete product with ID of ' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '? <a href="search-save.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="search-save.php">No</a>';
    exit();
  }
 if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
//remove item from system and delete its picture
//delete from database
    $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];

    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// unlink the image from server
// Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $pictodelete = ("../product_images/$id_to_delete.jpg");

    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
                unlink($pictodelete);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you verified the log file? If your `product_id` is an integer you should remove ''.

Comment: i just found out that when i press delete link the url showing with no proudct_id number like this http://localhost/shopone/admin/live/search-save.php?deleteid=    what did i missed!

Comment: From `$_GET` straight to a `mysql_query()` on a `DELETE`, oh boy you are in serious trouble.

Answer (score 1):

your this line

```
<a href='$row[$product_name]'>
```

is wrong use php tag , while problem is not due to this, it is due to next line

```
echo "<a href='../data/edit_product.php?pid=' . $product_id . ''>Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href='search-save.php?deleteid=' . $product_id . ''>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href='../data/edit-view.php?pid=' . $product_id . ''>View</a>";
```

when you will check you html you will get this

```
<a href="../data/edit_product.php?pid=" .="" 2="" ''="">Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="search-save.php?deleteid=" .="" 2="" ''="">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="../data/edit-view.php?pid=" .="" 2="" ''="">View</a>
```

let say product id is 2.
so it will not work.

**change php code to**

```
 echo '<a href="../data/edit_product.php?pid='. $product_id . '">Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="search-save.php?deleteid=' . $product_id . '">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="../data/edit-view.php?pid=' . $product_id . '">View</a>';
```